# Using stored query in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I want to use a SQL query in Entity Framework.

Here is my code:

```
 string sql = (@"SELECT G.GainId,
                (SELECT Name FROM Carrier WHERE CarrierId = G.CarrierId) AS Carrier,
                (SELECT Name + ' ' + Surname FROM [User] WHERE UserId = G.GainerId) AS Gainer,
                (SELECT Name + ' ' + Surname FROM [User] WHERE UserId = G.GiverId) AS Giver,
                (SELECT Name + ' ' + Surname FROM [User] WHERE UserId = G.CustomerId) AS Customer,
                    P.Name,
                    G.Gained,
                    G.Paid
                    FROM Gain AS G 
                    INNER JOIN Product AS P ON P.ProductId = G.ProductId");

            DataTable tbl = _context.Database.SqlQuery<DataTable>(sql) as DataTable;
```

But `tbl` is null. Do you have any suggestions? I am new with Entity Framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `SqlQuery` is not meant to return a `DataTable`. It's built to return your entity types as an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is your entity type. Use the below statement and remember that it's an enumerable type that's being returned. Now perform with it what you need.

```
var tbl = _context.Database.SqlQuery<{your entity type}>(sql)
```

### Edited

Yes, in fact you can very easily build this type. In fact, because the query seems so isolated you could probably build a private class inside of the class it's executed in so that how I'll build the example. However, that's something you need to decide. Below I'll give you a template for the class. The two properties with `??` I don't know exactly what type they correlate to so you'll need to plug those in.

```
private class QueryResult
{
    public int GainId { get; set; }
    public string Carrier { get; set; }
    public string Gainer { get; set; }
    public string Giver { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ?? Gained { get; set; }
    public ?? Paid { get; set; }
}
```

And then issue the statement like this...

```
var tbl = _context.Database.SqlQuery<QueryResult>(sql)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mike. I select values from a few tables in my sql query. So I don't have a entity type which has the properties of result data. That is why I want to use DataTable. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: I was thinking about it. Now I am sure this is the one way to solve my problem. Thank you for your help.